# Prevent case statement from continually asking for input so that I can carry out subsequent commands

Tags: linux, bash, case

I have the following code which includes a case statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

ltfs=/usr/local/bin/ltfs
INDEX_FILE=/opt/LTO6_Extract/index.txt

sudo umount /mnt/ltfs

 echo "Please push tape into drive and once the light stops flashing press ENTER"
        read enterme
        echo -n "Mounting the tape....."

        sudo $ltfs -o devname=/dev/nst1 /mnt/ltfs

# We need the index file to get list and names of tape content

ls -R /mnt/ltfs/ | grep \.mxf$ > $INDEX_FILE

clear


PS3='Please enter your choice: '
readarray -t options < $INDEX_FILE

select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
IFS=  read file <<< $opt
case  $opt  in


    $opt) echo you have chosen $file ;;


esac
done

echo $file | sed 's/.mxf//g'
```

My problem is that once a file is selected from the option menu, it subsequently keeps asking me to input further choices, but I only want to input one then carry out out the subsequent commands (in this case the subsequent command is at the bottom (`echo $file | sed 's/.mxf//g'`).
I'm sure this is something simple but I can't seem to work out what it is.

Comment: How could `case $opt in $opt` ever be useful? Anyway, `case` is not a loop, so your diagnostic is wrong.

Comment: I got this code from other scripts and it works to the point of "echo you have chosen $file" Care to suggest why it continues to ask me  for further choices after this and what I could amend to prevent it?

Comment: I would instead suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and perhaps the Stack Overflow [`bash` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: There's no looping due to `case` - but you do have `select` in your script, and that loops.  If you'd written a [mcve], that would have cleared up that misconception before you asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `break` the execution:

```
$opt) echo you have chosen $file
      break;;
```

[Documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_05.html)